# Problems with Context Api React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to use the Context Api to save the user data that comes from the firebase api, but when I get these values ​​in the component Index, it always returns the error:
TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Below is my code

Where do I create the Context

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

function AuthProvider({children}) {

  const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({});

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ userLogin, setUserLogin }} >
      { children }
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export { Context, AuthProvider }
```

Route File

```
 <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/cadastrar' element={<Register />} />
          <Route path='/recuperar-senha' element={<Recovery />} />
          <Route path='/anuncios' exact element={<Index />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Here where I set the context with firebase data

```
    const {setUserLogin} = useContext(Context);
    
      const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    
      const onSubmit = data => {
    
        const auth = getAuth();
    
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.email, data.password)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
    
            setUserLogin({user});
    
            navigate('/anuncios');
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            let erroMessage = localizeErrorMap(error.code)
    
            Toast('error', erroMessage);
          })
      };
```

I want to save the data in the context api and be able to take, for example, the component below and the others

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";

import  { Context } from '../providers/auth';


export default function Index() {

  const [user, setUserLogin] = useContext(Context);
  //console.log(user);
  return (
    <h1>Logado {user}</h1>
  )
}
```

I saw that in the browser console when I click on the component, it informs that the problem is in the line: const [user, setUserLogin] = useContext(Context);

Comment: const [user, setUserLogin] = useContext(Context);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context value is `{ userLogin, setUserLogin }`:

```
<Context.Provider value={{ userLogin, setUserLogin }}>
```

so you cannot destructure it into an array. Use `const { userLogin, setUserLogin } = useContext(Context)` instead:

```
export default function Index() {
  const { userLogin, setUserLogin } = useContext(Context);
  console.log(userLogin);
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! No longer returns the error, but unable to access the object.

In the console.log it returns _undefined_, but in the React Developer Tool, it shows that in the hook there is the Context.

Comment: I was able to access the context as follows:

`const userlogin = useContext(Context);
  console.log(userlogin.userLogin.email);`

Leaving the userLogin out of the object, is this a good practice or the correct way?

Comment: I had a typo in my answer (`userlogin` => `userLogin`), fixed it - userLogin shouldnt be undefined now